# Is "new changes" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

"Exam comes with 3 new changes"
Three big changes have been introduced in this year's Form Three examination under a new format.

Comment: If you don't like saying "new changes" , you could write "recent changes" .

Comment: ... as contrasted with 'earlier changes'. A → B → C →→→ ... → P → Q → R along one chain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's redundant, particularly when you're talking about repeated revisions. Each revision of a document incurs some changes. Talking about "new changes" or "the newest changes" specifies that you are talking about the most recent revision. You can say things like "No, those are the old changes, it's been revised since then", and the word "old" is not redundant. Or "These are new changes" to imply that they have not been seen before.

[Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+changes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnew%20changes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnew%20changes%3B%2Cc0) shows that "new changes" is indeed used in literature.

In your example, the word "new" implies that the method of change is new. Exams can be revised yearly by changing individual questions, so some changes are expected. The implication in your example is that these changes are more than the usual yearly revision (i.e. there might be some new format of question that wasn't in the exam in previous years, say an essay question or a multiple choice section).

Answer (score 0):

The use of the word “new” is largely redundant. The word “changes” states that there is something different, probably new. The possibility of old exists, but is fairly remote.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that it is not redundant. If you consider something that is "new", then it has not been previously existed. According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change), "change" means "to make different". In the case of a document, once an initial version is published, subsequent versions would constitute a change.

"new", meaning "different from one of the same category that has existed previously" or "having recently come into existence", would suggest that either:

1. the changes were made to a previously unaltered (original) part of the exam
2. the changes were made more closely to the present than perhaps other changes (or versions in the case of a document).